# How to pass in a int array as a value for a void method parameter?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a small console application for an ATM machine, and I am struggling with the Insert method of this Program, so it goes like this:

```
public void Insert(int[] cash) //I cannot change the type or parameter of the method
{

    for (int i = 0; i < cash.Length; i++) // using .Length input into the array
    {
        cash[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.In.ReadLine());
    }
    bool IsntAcceptable = cash.Intersect(AcceptableBanknotes).Any(); // Acepttable Banknotes variable is a array like this  private int []AcceptableBanknotes = { 5, 10, 20, 50, 100 };
    
    if (IsntAcceptable)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Only acceptable banknotes are 5, 10, 20, 50 and 100");
    }
    this.Balance += cash.Sum(); // add to balance

    Console.Write(this.Balance);
}
```

In my main it looks like this

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
// some other code here
        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the amount to deposit: ");
        atm.Balance = atm.Insert(Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Trim().Split(' '), Convert.ToInt32));
    }
```

but it just gives me an error of `Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'int'`

I would be very grateful for any help or guidance you could give me, thanks in advance!

Comment: But the `Insert` method reads from the console anyway, so any value you pass would be ignored other than the length.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama What am I supposed to put in Main() when I call the Insert() method then? It is supposed to have  a parameter

Comment: I don't really know what you want so I can't advise. I don't think it's right that `Insert` reads the values and discards the values in the `cash` array. You might as well pass `new int[5]` in from Main for all it matters since all you care about is the length of the array. If I were to develop this, I would remove the loop from the `Insert` method and place it in the `Main` method as it makes more sense there. Then you could pass in the final `cash` array.

Comment: The insert method is... problematic, as others have said. The problem is that you're completely intertwining the concepts of user input, user output and class behaviours. These should be in separate methods and probably separate classes too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to make `Insert` an extension method to `atm`. If that's the case your `Insert` method needs to be static and take `atm` as a parameter. If you're going down the route of extension methods I'd create a separate class for your extensions like this:

```
public static class AtmExtensions
{
    public static void Insert(this Atm atm, int[] cash)
    {
        // your logic.
    }
}
```

Where `Atm` is a separate class composing of the various properties like `Balance`.

Next thing is that your passing in the values read from the console only to ignore that later and read from the console again. Read the values from the console and then use that where needed. So in this case you can remove the `for loop` as you've already converted the values to `int`s.

Finally, you're expecting `Insert` to set `atm.Balance` in the `Main` method, but it's `void` so doesn't return anything, and is setting it anyway as part of the `Insert` method. So, I think what you're trying to achieve should look something like this:

Your `Atm` class:

```
public class Atm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    // other properties...
}
```

A new class for holding all your extension methods for `Atm`:

```
public static class AtmExtensions
{
    public static void Insert(this Atm atm, int[] cash)
    {
        var acceptableBanknotes = new int[] { 5, 10, 20, 50, 100 };

        if (cash.All(note => acceptableBanknotes.Contains(note)))
        {
            atm.Balance += cash.Sum();
            Console.Write(atm.Balance);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Only acceptable banknotes are 5, 10, 20, 50 and 100");
        }
    }
}
```

Called like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var atm = new Atm();
    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the amount to deposit: ");
    atm.Insert(Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Trim().Split(' '), Convert.ToInt32));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything from `Insert` that is the cause an issue. Just change it to normal call and it will work for you like below:

```
 atm.Insert(Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Trim().Split(' '), Convert.ToInt32));
```

or if you want to return something from that method then make that method with specific type as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error caused by putting an void type in the member variable atm.balance.

```
public int Insert(int[] cash) //I cannot change the type or parameter of the method
{

    for (int i = 0; i < cash.Length; i++) // using .Length input into the array
    {
        cash[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.In.ReadLine());
    }
    bool IsntAcceptable = cash.Intersect(AcceptableBanknotes).Any(); // Acepttable Banknotes variable is a array like this  private int []AcceptableBanknotes = { 5, 10, 20, 50, 100 };
    
    if (IsntAcceptable)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Only acceptable banknotes are 5, 10, 20, 50 and 100");
    }
    this.Balance += cash.Sum(); // add to balance
    //If you return Balance, you don't need this sentence.

    Console.Write(this.Balance);
    return Balance;
}
```

OR

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
// some other code here
        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the amount to deposit: ");
        atm.Insert(Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Trim().Split(' '), Convert.ToInt32));**
    }
```